# Switch View when in Xamarin.Forms (with XAML)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a page in a Xamarin.Forms app which displays data it loads from the web. I want to show a `ActivityIndicator` while the loading happens and a list view when the data is loaded. I want to do this in XAML.

Can I somehow do something like this:

```
if(dataIsLoading)
  <ActivityIndicator .../>
else
  <ListView ...>...</ListView>
```

Comment: you could bind the IsVisible property of each control to a VM property for dataIsLoading.  Or just do it in code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend doing something like this.

**ViewModel**

Create an IsBusy property.

```cs
private bool _isBusy = false;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get {  return _isBusy;  }
    set {  _isBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));  }
}
```

**Converter**

Create a NotConverter. This is just something that can flip booleans and be referenced in XAML.

```cs
public class NotConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        var boolean = false;

        if (Boolean.TryParse(value.ToString(), out boolean))
            return !boolean;

        return value;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

**View**

Reference the converter at the top of your XAML.

```cs
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MobileApp.Converter"
```

Declare your resource in your Pages resource dictionary.

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converter:NotConverter x:Key="NotConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then use this property in your XAML.

```xml
<Grid>
    <ListView IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}}" />
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: don't forget to declare your resource in the ResourceDictionary

Comment: oops, thanks @StephaneDelcroix, added the resource dictionary definition above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using RG.Plugins. You better [take a look](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).

**Xamarin Android**

Add `Rg.Plugin.popup.popUp.Init()` to `OnCreate` method in `MainActivity` class. the code looks like this:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            this.Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.Rgb(193,8,8));
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);  <=== Here

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApp();
        }
```

**Xamarin İOS**

Add `Rg.Plugin.popup.popUp.Init()` to `FinishedLaunching` method in `AppDelegate` class. the code looks like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(); <= Here
            LoadApplication(new App());
            
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

Finally, you add the page where the necessary actions are. the code looks like this:

```
public async override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            LoadingIndicator pg=new LoadingIndicator(Color.Red);
            await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(pg);
            
            //Your Process Here

            await PopupNavigation.RemovePageAsync(pg);
        }
```

Good Luck